# Spades - is the rule "Second hand plays low, Third hand plays high" important?

Tags: spades

In the game of Spades, is the [rule of thumb: "Third player play high"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_maxims) exists? (as in the game of Bridge)

The logic behind playing third high is is to prevents opponents winning a trick cheaply.

- In what situation this rule apply?
- What are the exceptions?

If the highest card in the suit (known as the Boss) wasn't played yet, should the third player play:

1. her highest card?
2. her highest card below the Boss-1?
3. Never play the King before the Ace is out but do play the Queen?

Comment: This is going to depend on how many tricks have been played in the suit among other things.

Comment: @JoeW that logic applies to bridge as well, yet the rule of thumb exists in bridge...

Comment: I dont see why this question is opinion-based.  This rule in Bridge is not opinion-based.

Comment: This question is most definitely NOT opinion based. There are sound reasons why the rule is accepted, as well as very definite and well understood exceptions - specifically to play top-of-a-sequence by Second Hand when held and a higher honour could be in either or both Third and Fourth Hand. Every *intermediate level* Bridge player knows these exceptions to the rule.

Comment: Note also that not a single one of the contributors who voted to close has ***even a single tag contribution*** in a relevant related game, such as Spades, Bridge, Euchre or Hearts. It is a farce that they felt entitled to vote rather than abstain on closing this question.

Comment: Situational card play is a well understood and documented art/science in trick-taking card games, best described in Contract Bridge writings such as [here](http://www.rpbridge.net/4l00.htm) and [here](http://www.rpbridge.net/7b57.htm) by multiple National Champion Richard Pavlicek. Many additional writings on the matter are available by Googling "*bridge second hand low*".

Comment: For Bridge in particular *card play* is often regarded as a science whereas bidding is an art; though this is certainly influenced by the visibility of all of *Dummy's* holdings.

Comment: Playing high from Second hand from *top-of-a-sequence* might be regarded as a *tactical* exception to the guideline Second Hand Low; but a strategic reason to play high would be when it is important to win the trick to place the lead in the correct partnership hand - such as to draw trumps or to give partner a revealed (or expected) ruff. All of this is science because it is so readily accessible to any player who is properly counting the cards.

Comment: A second *tactical* reason to play high as Second Hand would be to play highest from a two-card holding and second-highest from a four-card holding (when NOT also holding a sequence 3-cards or longer). These unblock the suit for partner, assist partner in playing his (presumed longer) holding, and assist partner in counting the hand out. However in the trump suit, always Spades when playing Spades of course, the rules and exceptions are often best played upside down when count-motivated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contract Bridge (whether Rubber or Duplicate) is a similar game to Spades but with greater information available to players do to the assets of Dummy being known to all. This makes card play in Bridge a true science. However many sound lessons can still be gleaned for use in other trick-taking games such as Spades, Hearts, Euchre and Whist.

Multiple National Champion Richard Pavlicek discusses many aspects of [Second hand play here](http://www.rpbridge.net/4l00.htm). The main exceptions to the guide of *Second Hand Low* are:

- With at least three *honours* where at least two are touching, play the highest of the *touching honours*. This is generally the same card one would lead as First Hand to open the suit.
- Cover an *honour* led with your highest card if (a) you have two or more cards higher or (b) it is the second or subsequent round of that suit being led by an honour from First Hand.
- From a *strategic* standpoint it is desired to win the trick (a) to lead trumps (Spades obviously in Spades); (b) to provide partner with a ruff before trumps are drawn; or (c) with a doubleton to unblock the suit and provide partner with a count in the suit.
- With holdings of only small cards there is great strategic and tactical value to agreeing with partner to play a *remainder-count echo* where (a) the lowest card is played from a remaining odd number of small cards; (b) the highest card is played from a doubleton remaining; and (c) the second highest card is played from a 4- or 6-card holding. When both partners have learned to read these count signals in building a complete count of the hand, some esoteric end-plays become accessible in the later tricks.

Numerous examples of how these guidelines assist in maximizing a partnership's rick-taking potential are readily available on the Internet's many Contract Bridge sites, usually under the main heading of *Defensive Card Play* [such as here (again) by Richard Pavlicek](http://www.rpbridge.net/rppl.htm).

**Terminology**:

- **Ruff** - When out of the suit led, playing a trump (ie a Spade) in an attempt to win the trick.
- **Honour** - While *Honours* are normally regarded as the cards *Ten* through *Ace*, for the purposes of this analysis, the *Nine* should be regarded as an honour also.
- **Touching Honours** - Two cards of the same suit, both *honours*, of adjacent rank such as AK, KQ, QJ, JT, or T9.
- **Doubleton** - A two-card holding in a suit. Depending on context this might refer to either the *original* holding of the suit, or to the *remaining* holding in the suit. Likewise **Singleton** and **Tripleton** for 1-card and 3-card holdings in a suit.
- **Echo** - The playing of small cards to the first two rounds of a suit such that the card played on the first round is higher than that played on the second. It is usually done with an even number of cards in the suit to assist partner in counting the hands around the table.

  In the Trump suit (always Spades playing Spades) partnerships may find it useful to reverse the signal (echoing with three or five) to explicitly signal possession of an additional Trump (ie Spade) and an ability to ruff in a side suit.

**Note on *echoing***:

While the value is undoubtedly reduced when both Dummy is unexposed and Partner is blind to the meaning, my recommendation would be to still make these plays. They will cost little, and have tactical value in and of themselves - most particularly playing second highest from a 4-card holding (led by 0 or 1 honour) on the first round.

**Note on *importance*** of these guidelines

In my university days I shared a house with a group that enjoyed the [3-player Whist variant *Nine-Five-Two* (or Sergeant Major)](https://www.pagat.com/whist/sergeant.html). It employs a *cascading* scoring system that results in better card play early on improving one's hand in subsequent deals. My deeper understanding of card combinations and greater discipline at *counting* the hand was worth perhaps 1/4 of a trick each hand - with the result that I won almost twice my share of games, and virtually 100% of games that lasted longer than 7 or 8 deals. Yes, better card play will very much influence one's success in trick-taking card games.

Comment: while I really like your answer, my concern is that this answer is true for Bridge but maybe need some adjustments for Spades.  I think that the considerations in Spades are much simpler, e.g., the players I know don't use the 'ask for count / attitude' convention (since less information is reveled).

Comment: As an occasional spades player but not a bridge player, I have no idea what the terminology here means. Honours, touching honours, a ruff, a doubleton, a count, etc.

Comment: Honours - high cards: 10 to A.  


Touching honours - for example K,Q or Q,J,10.  


 Ruff - a cut - playing spade in a trick lead by non spade.  

Doubleton - a suit with only 2 cards.  

a count - a Bridge convention of signaling to your partner how many cards you have in that suit.

Comment: @Samthere: Does the new section address your questions sufficiently?

Comment: @ForgetIwaseverhere Yes, that's much more understandable to a layperson, thanks!

Comment: @Samthere: Thanks for pointing that out. The extension makes the answer much better.