# How do Jokers change the bidding in Spades?

Tags: variants, spades, trick-taking-games

In the game of Spades, there are several popular jokers variations which add the two jokers, named big joker and small joker (BJ, SJ) to the ♠ suit while removing the 2♡,2♦.

In the **simple jokers variation**:

- ♠ suit contains 15 cards, sorted from high to low: BJ, SJ, A, K, ..., 2.
- ♥,♦ contain only 12 cards: A, K, ..., 3
- ♣ have 13 cards as normal A, K, ..., 2

What are the major differences in the **bidding** of the simple Jokers variation, compared to the normal Spades game?

Comment: This is a difficult question, but by no means "too broad"? An [earlier question on **Spades**](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/43272/spades-is-the-rule-second-hand-plays-low-third-hand-plays-high-important) I was able to answer based on my Contract Bridge experience, but I have never played Spades itself. However the specific strategic consequences of there being two more trumps and two 12-card suits is by no means *unanalyzable*.

Comment: The main complexity is that instead of 4 suits of 13 cards each, the deck now comprises one 15-card suit, one 13-card suit, and two 12-card suits. Thus the relative value of cards, in the three side suits particularly, is subtly different. The biggest direct play difference probably hinges on the change in the increased  *a priori* probability of a red-suit singleton or void compared to the baseline probability for a 13-card suit (now just Clubs).

Comment: I haven't rolled the mathematics yet, but in particular I suspect that these two probabilities jump significantly when one holds 4 or 5 cards in a red suit compared to the same holding in Clubs

Comment: right, in order to evaluate the value of high cards I run Monte Carlo simulations.  needed just small tweaks to get good evaluation for the 12 and 15 suits.

Comment: what about changes in the play? now it is more likely to get a hand with e.g. 8 spades.

Comment: Such extremes are irrelevant - When one picks up one's cards it is already apparent whether one is holding an 8-card Spades suit or not, and bidding is subsequent to that revelation. Of greater consequence would be the probability of partner or an opponent having a 5+ card Spade suit given one's own (known) length holding.

Comment: P.S. Note [my Meta question](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1738/why-do-contributors-with-no-experience-with-trick-taking-card-games-insist-on-cl) on the ethics of questions being closed by contributors with zero experience in the game in question, or even in any related game.

Comment: I'm curious about your Monte Carlo simulations. (1) Are you familiar with the 4-3-2-1 [Work Point Count](http://www.bridgeguys.com/Conventions/valuation/work_point_count.html) used in Bridge? (2) What do your simulations show is the relative weight for honours in red suits compared to Clubs?

Comment: I am familiar with the 4-3-2-1 Work Point Count used in Bridge, however I don't use it.  Instead I estimate the strength of the Ace, King, Queen by assuming they only lose if someone trumps that suit.  So Ace gets the trick if no opponent is void, King gets the trick if no opponent is void or singleton and queens gets it if no opponent is void / singleton or doubleton.

Comment: We call that *Losing Trick Count* in Bridge. It works well for highly distributional deals with good fits, quite poorly for balanced deals and mis-fits. Experience in Bridge suggests that it is more accurate as a fine-tuning of Work Point Count than as a stand-alone evaluation method. Of course Bridge offers multiple rounds of bidding, which is ***a big deal***.

Comment: Have you seen this Wikipedia article on [Hand Evaluation in Contract Bridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hand_evaluation)? You might consider a *Quick Trick* evaluation in preference to *Losing Trick Count*.